# refresh page content not using .load in ajax

Tags: php, ajax, laravel-5

I am using `.load` to update my list, but this is not right approach as it get nested each time. what would be the alternate. I am new to Ajax.

```
    $(document).on('click','#npDelete',function(){
            var dataId = $(this).data("id");

            alert(dataId);
            $.ajax({
                type:'get',
                url:"{!! URL::to('deleteproject') !!}",
                data:{'id':dataId

,},

            success:function(data){
                console.log('success');
                console.log(data);
                console.log(data.length);
                $("#projects1").load("projects");
            },
            error:function(){

            },
        });
});
```

Projects is the page which contains the list of projects from database. So each time I delete a project the list is updated, its working fine but each time the ajax request is called plus one(+1) time

Comment: Don't use GET requests to delete things! GET requests are supposed to be **safe** and repeatable!

Answer (score 0):

The quick and dirty solution would be to:

- Import only the `#projects1` element instead of the whole document
- Replace the contents of the existing document's `#projects1` element's *parent* element (so that the `#projects1` element itself is replaced)

Such:

```
$("#projects1").parent().load("projects #projects1");
```

… but a nicer solution would be to have `{!! URL::to('deleteproject') !!}` return JSON that gave a `true` or `false` response and then delete the element that was actually clicked:

Add `var $clicked_element = $(this);` above `var dataId = $(this).data("id");` and the you can `$clicked_element.remove()` when the request is successful. (Or possibly something like `$clicked_element.parents("tr").remove()` … but I'm having to speculate as to what your HTML looks like).

---

NB: Your HTML implies that you have multiple elements with the id `#npDelete`. This is invalid HTML. Don't do that. Use a class to identify a *group* of related elements. Use an id only to identify a unique element.

Comment: dirty solution doesn't works it delete one element and update the list with showing nothing, like there are four elements in list, I delete one and the list is updated with 0 elements instead of three.

Comment: Typo. Missed the `1` off the ID. (Tip: If you are numbering your ID and then hardcoding references to specific numbers, you are probably doing something wrong).

Answer (score -2):

do

```
$("#projects1").html("projects");
```

and i suggest you use

```
$(document).ready(function(){});
```

or

```
$("#target").on('click',function(){});
```

at the beginning of your code instead of using `$(document).on('click',function(){});`

Comment: *`$("#projects1").html("projects");`* — Now you are replacing the content of the element with the text "projects" instead of the contents of the URL "projects". You've broken it.

Comment: *`$(document).ready(function(){});` or `$("#target").on('click',function(){});`* — Now the click event won't trigger for elements that are added after the initial page load. You've broken it more.